# Select distinct on declared table

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I need to create concatenated query will get data with checking data in other tables.

Firstly I declared (and filled it) two tables with list of ID I'll check in other tables. On next step (2) I declared new table and filled it values I get by some checking params. This table contains only one column (ID).
After filling if I execute `SELECT DISTINCT` query from this table I'll get really unique ID. It's OK.

But on next step (3) I declare more one table and filling it by 3 tables. Of course it contains many duplicates. But I must create this query for checking and concatenating. And after that if I execute `select distinct h from @NonUnicalConcat` it returns many duplicate IDs.

What I did wrong? Where is an error?

```
USE CurrentBase;
--STEP 1
DECLARE @TempCSTable TABLE(TempTableIDColumn int);
INSERT INTO @TempCSTable VALUES('3'),('4');
DECLARE @TempCVTable TABLE(TempTableIDColumn int);
INSERT INTO @TempCVTable VALUES('2'),('13');
--STEP 2
DECLARE @TempIdTable TABLE(id int);
INSERT INTO @TempIdTable
       SELECT TT1.ID
       FROM Table1 AS TT1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ID = TT1.OptionalColumn
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 AS TT2 ON TT2.ID = TT1.OptionalColumn
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 AS TT3 ON TT3.ID = TT2.OptionalColumn
       WHERE TT1.ValueDate > '2020-06-30'
             AND TT1.ValueDate < '2020-08-04'
             AND TT1.OptBool = '1'
             AND TT1.OptBool2 = '0'
             AND EXISTS
                        (
                            SELECT Table5.ID
                            FROM Table5
                            WHERE Table5.ID = TT1.ID
                                  AND Table5.CV IN
                                                           (
                                                               SELECT TempTableIDColumn
                                                               FROM @TempCVTable
                                                           )
                                  AND Table5.OptBool = '1'
                        )
             AND EXISTS
                        (
                            SELECT Table6.ID
                            FROM Table6
                            WHERE Table6.IID = TT3.ID
                                  AND Table6.CS IN
                                                            (
                                                                SELECT TempTableIDColumn
                                                                FROM @TempCSTable
                                                            )
                        );
SELECT distinct * FROM @TempIdTable;--this code realy select distinct
--STEP 3
DECLARE @NonUnicalConcat TABLE(c int, s int, h int);
INSERT INTO @NonUnicalConcat
       SELECT TT1.TempTableIDColumn AS cc, 
              TT2.TempTableIDColumn AS ss, 
              TT3.id AS hh
       FROM @TempCVTable AS TT1, 
            @TempCSTable AS TT2, 
            @TempIdTable AS TT3
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
                        (
                            SELECT HID
                            FROM OtherBase.dbo.Table1
                            WHERE HID = TT3.id
                                  AND CS = TT2.TempTableIDColumn
                                  AND CV = TT1.TempTableIDColumn
                        );
select distinct h from @NonUnicalConcat;--this code return many duplicates
```

Comment: Ignoring the cross join in the query that populates `@NonUnicalConcat`, the use of error-prone old-style joins, the inconsistent coding style, and cryptic names, what you claim should be impossible. Can you show a small sample of duplicate IDs in the resultset of your last query?

Comment: @SMor of course you right! It was my mistake! Before executing `select distinct h from NonUnicalConcat` was placed some code and added duplicates. Thank you!